# Flutter content inside of container is clipping

Tags: android, flutter

I am creating a flutter screen in which I have two nested views. But my child's view's content is clipping. Here's what I am doing,

```
class PageStates extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("App"),
      ),
      body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black)),
          child: StaggeredGrid.count(crossAxisCount: 4, children: const [
            StaggeredGridTile.count(
                crossAxisCellCount: 1, mainAxisCellCount: 1, child: Tile()),
            StaggeredGridTile.count(
                crossAxisCellCount: 3, mainAxisCellCount: 1, child: Tile()),
            StaggeredGridTile.count(
                crossAxisCellCount: 1, mainAxisCellCount: 1, child: Tile()),
            StaggeredGridTile.count(
                crossAxisCellCount: 3, mainAxisCellCount: 1, child: Tile())
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code for child view,

```
class Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  const Tile({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1.0)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: HexColor("#00000000"),
                offset: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
                blurRadius: 1.0,
              ),
            ]),
        child: const Text("Some very long text"));
  }
}
```

Here is the output,
[image: Output]

Comment: So what is the expected output?

Comment: The text should auto-resize as per the size of the parent, In my case every child box should show, "Some very long text" or at least show truncating text.

Comment: For truncating simply give the `Text` a `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` or something.  I'm not really that familiar with `flutter_staggered_grid_view ` that you seem to use but it looks like it simply forces the cell height to be the same as the cell width, making them square but maybe it's configurable.